# Method of evaluating the feature map of a polynomial kernel feature mapping

Tags: kernel-trick, kalman-filter, kernel-mean-embedding

I'm attempting to implement an adaptive kernel Kalman filter following this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.08300, but I'm struggling to find a method of evaluating the feature mapping for a polynomial kernel $K(x,y)=(x^{T}y+c)^{d}$ with the input (state) dimension is larger than 2. For the scenarios I inted to use the filter for the state could be $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^{10}$ which leads to some fairly high-dimensional feature mappings.

The idea is to map the filter state to a kernel mean embedding to perform the filter update. The notes I've found have feature mappings $\phi{}(x)$ of different dimensions for the homogeneous quadratic kernel but want to see if there was a simpler method of finding the explicit feature mapping. My question is if there is a formula for generating the feature map for the polynomial kernel given a n-dimensional input and kernel of degree d? Probably a bit of a newbie question but cheers for any help in advance!

Comment: Could you state more clearly what your question is? You just write "if there was a simpler method of finding the explicit feature mapping" but you neither describe the other methods nor tell us why they are not simple enough for you.

Comment: Of course, my apologies! So given a polynomial kernel of degree d and input vector x of dimension n, one could expand the kernel and generate the feature mapping. For any higher dimension x and for even quadratic/quartic kernels which I'm interested in, the number of terms is significant and expanding this manually would take a long time. Is there a formula for generating the feature map for a polynomial kernel?

Comment: I understand you are looking for an explicit formula for the features to do some manual calculations. You can find such a formula in the wikpedia article on the [polynomial kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_kernel). But note that the beauty of kernel methods mainly lies in the fact, that an explicit representation of the feature space is not necessary.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that fact, and most of the available notes and literature is focussed around the SVM applications. For the Kalman filter implementation I require the explicit feature mapping to move from the state space to the RKHS where the Kalman gain is calculated. I'll have another look at the Wikipedia article, thanks!